# SQL Server dynamic Field Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that joins two tables and gives that result:

```
A.ID    A.SelectedField B.ID    B.Field1    B.Field2    B.Field3 
1           Field1           1    **0**          20           30
2           Field2           2    11             **21**        0 
3           Field3           3    12             22           **0** 
4           Field3           4    13             0            **33**
```

And I need to retrieve only the rows in which the selected field is not 0, so my desired result is:

```
A.ID    A.SelectedField B.ID    B.Field1    B.Field2    B.Field3 
2            Field2          2    11             21           0 
4            Field3          4    13             0            33
```

How do I do that?

Comment: how do you know what the selected field is?

Comment: The selected field name is mentioned in A.SelectedField,
To be clearer: I need to check for each row if the value of 
B.(A.SelectedField) is not 0.

Comment: You've got something wrong with your data model if parts of the data have ended up being placed in *meta* data (i.e. you've got data you're wanting to write queries about that's ended up in column *names*).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
WHERE 
 CASE A.SelectedField WHEN 'Field1' THEN B.Field1
                      WHEN 'Field2' THEN B.Field2
                      WHEN 'Field3' THEN B.Field3
                      ELSE 0 -- default value
 END <> 0
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59243/2)**

Comment: @HamletHakobyan `ELSE` is if `SelectedField` comes with value which is neither `Field1`, `Field2` nor `Field3`. Choose 0 or 1 if you want those rows or not. Of-course there aren't any in example but case should be handled.

Comment: In case of the SelectedField not match any of, the result of `CASE` statement is `null` so null<>0 always false.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A.SelectedField = 'Field1' AND  B.Field1 <> 0 THEN  A.SelectedField 
            WHEN A.SelectedField = 'Field2' AND  B.Field2 <> 0 THEN  A.SelectedField        
            WHEN A.SelectedField = 'Field3' AND  B.Field3 <> 0 THEN  A.SelectedField 
            ELSE NULL
        END
```

Comment: I don't think the question is where each field is not equal to zero.  `A.ID` 2 has a 0 in is `B.Field3`.  But, that record is in the desired output.  So your query would not work.

Comment: opss I read his question and answered the it without looking at his desired output, his question contradicts his own desired output ...